# R Data.Table Solution for DPLYR Resolution

Tags: r, data.table

```
data1=data.frame("StudentID"=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6),
                 "Time"=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6),
                 "var1"=c(0,0,0,NA,1,2,0,1,2,2,2,2,0,0,NA,1,1,1,NA,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,NA,0,0,0,0,0,1,NA,NA))


library(dplyr)
data2 <- group_by(data1, StudentID) %>% 
  slice(seq_len(min(which(var1 == 1), n())))
```

After much attempt I am able to obtain 'data2' from 'data1'. The rule is simple that in data1 FOR EACH STUDENTID if var1 equals to 1, keep that row and delete everything after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want a similar option in `data.table`, either use the condition in `.SD`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data1)[, .SD[c(seq_len(min(which(var1 == 1), .N)))],.(StudentID)]
```

or use row index with `.I`, and extract the column as `$V1` to subset the dataset

```
setDT(data1)[data1[, .I[c(seq_len(min(which(var1 == 1), .N)))],.(StudentID)]$V1]
```

Or with `match`

```
setDT(data1)[, .SD[seq_len(min(match(1, var1), .N, na.rm = TRUE))], .(StudentID)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to find the rows where `var1 == 1L` and use `unique` to select the top row then perform a non-equi inner join to filter the rows:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data1)
f <- unique(data1[var1==1L | c(diff(StudentID) != 0L, TRUE)], by="StudentID")[, var1 := NULL]
f[data1, on=.(StudentID, Time>=Time), nomatch=0L]
```

timing code:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data1)
DT <- rbindlist(replicate(2e5, data1, simplify=FALSE))
DT[, StudentID:=c(1L, 1L+cumsum(diff(StudentID)!=0L))]
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(times=1L,
    mtd0 = a1 <- {
        DT[DT[, .I[c(seq_len(min(which(var1 == 1), .N)))],.(StudentID)]$V1]    
    },
    mtd1 = a2 <- {
        f <- unique(DT[var1==1L | c(diff(StudentID) != 0L, TRUE)], by="StudentID")[, var1 := NULL]
        f[DT, on=.(StudentID, Time>=Time), nomatch=0L]
    }
)
fsetequal(a1, a2)
#[1] TRUE
```

timings:

```
Unit: seconds
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 mtd0 2.830089 2.830089 2.830089 2.830089 2.830089 2.830089     1
 mtd1 1.153433 1.153433 1.153433 1.153433 1.153433 1.153433     1
```